# Sorting unique consecutive pairs of items in a pandas dataframe with complex outliers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

### Input

My data is contained in pandas dataframe (on a column). For the sake of this problem, assume that it looks something like so (where we use the numpy version of a small view of the dataframe):

```
array([['i', 101505.92499994699, 'A'],
       ['m', 101624.589999905, 'A'],
       ['i', 101686.209999956, 'B'],
       ['o', 101696.209999956, 'A'],
       ['p', 101738.094999921, 'A'],
       ['m', 101803.725000005, 'B'],
       ['o', 101847.539999988, 'A'],
       ['p', 101943.93000006699, 'B'],
       ['o', 102031.829999993, 'B'],
       ['r', 102064.49000001901, 'A'],
       ['r', 102175.569999963, 'B'],
       ['a', 102215.54500004301, 'A'],
       ['n', 102352.590000024, 'A'],
       ['a', 102379.3899999, 'B'],
       ['t', 102459.574999986, 'A'],
       ['n', 102469.35499995, 'B'],
       [' ', 102580.80999995599, 'A'],
       ['t', 102588.555000024, 'B'],
       ['e', 102672.149999999, 'A'],
       ['e', 102753.13999992801, 'B'],
       [' ', 102774.405000033, 'B'],
       ['x', 102836.609999882, 'A'],
       ['x', 102962.774999905, 'B'],
       ['a', 102990.560000064, 'A'],
       ['a', 103132.16499984301, 'B'],
       ['α', 103372.664999915, 'A'],
       ['α', 103879.135000054, 'A'],
       ['α', 103911.880000029, 'A'],
       ['α', 103944.404999958, 'A'],
       ['α', 103977.625000058, 'A'],
       ['α', 104008.33999994199, 'A'],
       ['α', 104018.140000058, 'B'],
       ['α', 104279.709999915, 'A'],
       ['α', 104418.629999971, 'B'],
       ['t', 104550.4699999, 'A'],
       ['t', 104640.194999985, 'B'],
       ['a', 104689.35999996, 'A'],
       ['n', 104830.58999991, 'A'],
       ['z', 104930.58999991, 'A'],
       ['a', 104846.105000004, 'B'],
       ['n', 104946.105000004, 'B']], dtype=object)
```

Now, I have about 2000 of these arrays and each one has on average about 300-400 rows. So there is no massive need for performance here.

Back to our MWE list, we are only interested in the order of the array using **the first column**:

```
array(['i', 'm', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'm', 'o', 'p', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'a',
       't', 'n', ' ', 't', 'e', 'e', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'a', 'a', 'α', 'α',
       'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 't', 't', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n'],
      dtype=object)
```

But there is an additional caveat: the middle-column (the numerical one) is a time-stamp and thus has to be monotonically increasing in order for the final result to make sense.

### Desired output

Now then, the way the items in the list **should** be structured is that of consecutive pairs (but for data-collection reasons, they are not). So here is the sorted column we are aiming for:

```
array(['i', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'p', 'p', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'a', 'n',
       'n', 't', 't', ' ', ' ', 'e', 'e', 'x', 'x', 'a', 'a', 'α', 'α',
       'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 'α', 't', 't', 'a', 'a', 'n', 'n'],
      dtype=object)
```

where the last column looks as so:

```
array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A',
       'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A',
       'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
      dtype=object)
```

### Additional caveats

- Now the hawk-eyed reader will note that I have left-out two rows
  which are in the original array. This is also because of data-collection errors. For a pair to be 'valid' and hence feature in
  the final sorted array, it needs to have an `'A'` and `'B'` value in the
  last column. So what is missing in the final output is the fourth row from the top and the third from the bottom because they do not meet the condition.
- But somtimes we also get sequences of symbols which only have an 'A' but eventually get a matching 'B' like the sequences of `'α','α','α','α','α','α','α'` -- sequences such as these are valid because eventhough they are not a pair they belong to the same group on account of the 'start' indicator `'A'` and the end indicator `'B'` of this symbol. But if there is no matching end or start indicator for a symbol then it has to be removed from the final list.
- The data collection is somewhat random so things appear out of order a lot.

I am looking for help with a method that can sort the rows of arrays like this one, into the required pair-sequential order. Thanks in advance and please let me know if it not clear what I am looking for and I shall add more description.